# Create a class with objects of type List

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I am very new to JAVA, how do I create a class with objects of type List.

```
public class Information {

    public String Name;
    public double Age;
    **public List<String> vechicleType=** new ArrayList<String>();**

    }
```

I get an error as follows:

```
The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>
```

Is it possible to use it within hashmap like for Eg:

I want to use an HashMap

```
HashMap<String, Information> hm = new HashMap<String,Information>();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You must have the wrong import in your class.

Do not import [`java.awt.List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/List.html) but [`java.util.List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Comment: WOW!! I did not see that coming! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user1799214 this is explained in the dup Q/A and with more details.